# Implement like functionality using ManyToMany relationship

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have these database tables

```
USER
id int
name varchar

ANSWER
id int
message varchar

user_answer_likes
user FK -> USER.id
answer FK -> ANSWER.id
```

The user_answer_likes table is there so users can like answers but only once. I have a problem on how to implement this in my Spring project though.

In the Answer Entity, I'd like to have the total number of likes for an Answer. How would I be able to achieve this, say for example with an `int` property in the Answer Entity?

Comment: That shouldn't be a property of Answer. it should be the result of a query defined in a repository.

Comment: @JBNizet But if it's part of the Answer Entity AND defined in a (native) query defined in the AnswerRepository, there's nothing wrong with that, right?

Answer (score 1):

1) In your case, you have this relation:

1. One person ---> Many Like_Answer
2. One Like_Answer --> One Person
3. One Answer ---> Many Like_Answer
4. One Like Answer --> One Answer

So you can use @ManytoOne relation between tables.
And use the two foreign keys PersonID and AnswerID for construct the Compound Key Like_Answer (PersonID, AnswerID).

2) For the other question: the total number of likes for an Answer, shouldn't be a property of Answer.